# Is it possible to find distance from bottom to current scroll state in jquery

Tags: javascript

Suppose have scrolled down to the middle of a web page.

Is it possible to find the distance, in length or pixels, from the bottom?

Like when scroll-bar hits the bottom then its 0 but if it 500px from the bottom then I need that *500px* value.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's not so precise but works:

```
var scrollPosition = window.pageYOffset;
var windowSize     = window.innerHeight;
var bodyHeight     = document.body.offsetHeight;

alert(Math.max(bodyHeight - (scrollPosition + windowSize), 0));
```

Comment: I don't understand , how can i get the data for image with id img1.
I don't want body

Comment: This answered your question - you made no mention of images of ID's. Please re-phrase your question.

Comment: This solution only address the window itself, and not any element which has a scroll, which the same problem applies to. (also the OP didn't specifically say it's about the window scroll)

Answer (score 5):

Also try this:

```
$(document).height() - ($('body').height() + $('body').scrollTop())
```

Answer (score 3):

Tweaking rkleine's answer. I found it was actually, this:

```
$(document).height() - ($(window).height() + $('body').scrollTop())
```

i.e. $(window) for the height not $('body')

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code in vanilla JS:

```
var distanceFromBottom = document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight - window.scrollY
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var distanceFromBottom = $(document).height() - $(window).height() - $(document).scrollTop();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to further tweak previous answers to make it work:

```
distFromBottom = $(document).height() - $(window).scrollTop() - $(window).height();
```

Just to break it down:

```
let bottomToWinTop = $(document).height() - $(window).scrollTop();
```

This gets the distance from the bottom of document to the top of the window. 
Since window height will vary, subtract the current window height to get the offset from the bottom

```
let bottomToWinBottom = bottomToWinTop - $(window).height();
```

Now `bottomToWinBottom = distFromBottom = 0` when user is scrolled completely down the page and as they scroll up, it's value is the distance below the window which makes for a good indicator of vertical positioning.